# YUI3 files served by Yahoo are not minified?

Tags: minify, yui3

I recently started learning YUI3. I started with the link

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/yui/#start

Which says I need to include the seed file

`<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>`

And other files can be loaded automatically based on what we need. However I am noticing that these files are not minified. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is, your YUI() statement can accept a config object, check it doesn't contain the flag filter: 'raw'

ie if it reads

```
YUI({
    filter: 'raw'
}).use(
```

then remove the filter property

ref - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/yui/#loader

Comment: Just be sure to actually check the source.  For example the doc page for http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/yui/yui-core.html has "YUI().use(", but the actual source for the example uses the "raw" filter.  It's also possible (though unlikely) that Y.config.filter is being set elsewhere in the code.